# Is there a way to fix this box issue on materialize Css dropdown?

Tags: css, materialize

I am learning materialize CSS. I encounter an error When I hover on the dropdown. it creates weird the box. How to fix it[image: on Practice this black box I want to remove it]

and my code is

```
<nav class="blue darken-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">FSPN</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >About FSPN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-trigger" data-target="practice-menu">Practice <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down fa-sm right"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul id="practice-menu" class='dropdown-content'>
                <li  ><a href="#">Corporate Law</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Banking & Finance</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#"> Litigation & Arbitration</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Conveyance & Real Estate</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Loan Recoveries & Restructuring</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Mining, Oil & Gas</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Tax Law</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Regulatory</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-trigger {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```